# Где взять файл преобразования для деобфускации для консоли Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

В гугл плей консоли есть раздел Android Vitals и там есть вкладка "Файлы деобфускации". Для каждой версии приложения можно загрузить файлы преобразования, чтоб можно было смотреть более подробные отчёты об ошибках. Но где взять эти файлы я никак не могу понять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ProGuard saves the file in the app `<module-name>/build/outputs/mapping/release/` directory.

Источник: [документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#decode-stack-trace)

Comment: У меня в outputs только две папки - logs и apk

Comment: @cheerful_weasel очевидно, у вас не включена обфускация и не нужно загружать файлы преобразования. Зачем вам понадобилось это?

Comment: Я думал это поможет при просмотре отчётов об ошибках от пользователей.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel Это поможет только если приложение обфусцировано, что стектрейсы приняли читабельный вид. В ином случае не нужно.

Comment: Вот спасибо. Проголосовал. Нигде не мог найти где этот файл, а гугл никак не мог намекнуть